# Maximum call stack size exceeded in JQuery for firing focus of next element inside focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting this error "maximum call stack size exceeded". what is the reason here & how can i achieve what i am trying to do.

In Jquery/JavaScript I am trying to focus next control for changing tab index of current control by pressing tab key. the current control will be any select (dropdownlist) .

My code :

```
$(document).on('focusout', 'select', function () {


                        $(this).click();
                        var fields = $(this).parents('form:eq(0),body').find('button,input,textarea,select');
                        var index = fields.index(this);
                        if (index > -1 && (index + 1) < fields.length) {

                             fields.eq(index + 1).focus();
                            //checkDateAndTime();
                        }
                    });
```

NB: I have tried to fix by setTimeout function but if i do that i am not getting that error but the select list is closing if i try to populate the options on click.

I had to do this because i had to fire  $(this).click(); because if i dont do that the ui of dropdownlist options are not closing automatically in tab key pressed but this issues were not coming in Mozilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you don't need to have a ***event delegation*** syntax, unless you don't have dynamic elements generated via some code or ajax after page load.

The other thing i noticed on `focusout` you are again doing `.click()` on the same element, which in turn get focus.

You are using `.parents()` method to traverse up, which is in someway responsible for the the error you got.

---

I would suggest you to do this:

```js
$('select').on('focusout', function() {
  var fields = $(this).closest('form').find('select');
  var idx = fields.index(this);
  if (idx > -1 && (idx + 1) < fields.length) {

    fields.eq(idx + 1).focus();
    //checkDateAndTime();
  }
});
```

Comment: I used your code. it is not giving error .. but  $(this).click(); is the reason. if i use this.click() in your code too its giving the error. as i told i need to fire the .click of the same control to close the opened dropdown option of the select because my select  has a special dropdown.js applied & the options are not closing.

Comment: @SouravMukherjee Ah! Okay then you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event to bubble up to the dom or you can hide it programatically too.